# How to access the history object in Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have an if conditional that looks like this:

```
if (history.state !== null && history.state.query)
```

The issue is that while this doesn't work in Jest, as `history` is an empty object in my tests.

What needs to be done in my tests to use the `history` object? I'm running this using React on a Node.js server. Not sure if this matters, but I'm also using React Router.

Test case:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  window.ga = jest.fn();
  window.analytics = jest.fn();
  window.analytics.track = jest.fn();
});

it('should set up props from history state', () => {
  let location = {
    pathname: '/explore',
    query: {
      query: 'yahoo',
    },
  };

  global.history = { state: { query: 'google'} };

  const wrapper = mount(
    <LandingPage location={location} />
  );

  console.log("global.history.state: " + global.history.state); // prints null
});
```

Part of the component (can't put the whole component):

```
if (props.location && props.location.pathname === '/explore') {
  explorePath = true;
  skipIntro = true;
  explore = true;

  /* checks if history.state is not equal to null
   * if check passes, search query and results will appear
   */
  if (history.state !== null && history.state.query) {
    currentValue = history.state.query;
    employeeMin = history.state.eMin;
    employeeMax = history.state.eMax;
    revenueMin = history.state.rMin;
    revenueMax = history.state.rMax;
  }
} else {
  explore = skipIntro;
}
```

Comment: What version of react-router do you use? Do you retrieve history from props  in your component?

Comment: Well you could mock `history` by adding `state.query` to the empty object ?

Comment: @hinok I use the global `history` from `window`. I believe the version is `3.0.2`.

Comment: @VincentTaing I've tried mocking, but it didn't work when I did `global.window = {history:{state:{query:"..."}}};` Am I supposed to mock it in a different way?

Comment: @RaDeuX can you show us which component you are trying to test and the test case ?

Comment: @VincentTaingn Updated with test case and part of the component.

Comment: I know I am a bit late to the party, but I found this plugin to help us mock the `react-router`'s objects. Please have a look https://github.com/pshrmn/react-router-test-context

Answer (score 18):

You need to use `createMemoryStore` to mock `history` like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history'

import Page from '../Page'

describe('<Page />', () => {
  it('should render correctly', () => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory('/dashboard')
    const renderedComponent = shallow(
      <Page history={history} />
    )
    expect(renderedComponent).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

References:

- https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/465#issuecomment-193541772
- https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4558#issuecomment-281063572

Answer (score 2):

This worked for my scenario, which seems similar to yours.

```
beforeAll(() => {
  window.history.replaceState({query: 'google'}, 'MOCK');
});
```

Comment: In my case I had to insert a second argument to make it work, `window.history.replaceState({query: 'google'}, null, 'MOCK');`